# Convert xml to annotated bean Java

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, javabeans

```
<bean id="pdf" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
          p:url="classpath:jasperReports/test.jrxml"
          p:reportDataKey="datasource" />
```

Trying to convert the above code to annoted `@Bean` but failed to do. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but just create the object and set the attributes. Any specifics/error messages when you try to autowire it?

```
@Bean
public JasperReportsPdfView getJasperReports(){
    JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
    view.setUrl("classpath:jasperReports/test.jrxml");
    view.setReportDataKey("datasource");
    return view;
}
```